# Как правильно паблишить .net core проекты?

Tags: iis, .net-core

Добрый день, чтобы паблишить сайт на сервер приходится останавливать его в IIS.
Если этого не сделать получается вот такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, можно ли как-то обойти остановку IIS?

Comment: Можно стопнуть сайт(в IIS Manager) => запаблишить => стартануть сайт. Есть подозрение что можно только обновлять неисполняемые файлы , или исполняемые при условии что они не загружены в память компьютера => можно сделать вывод что если файл в памяти , то его нельзя обновить и как результат возникает необходимость стопать сайт

Comment: Примерно так и думал, спасибо